# Mysql - Select & Group rows with A column, and B column where A.value and B.value = x and y or y and x

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table which has 2 numeric (`int`) values (IDs) as `sender_id` and `receiver_id`.

What I'm trying to do is group these rows as "conversations". the conversation between :

```
sender_id = 1, and receiver_id = 5,
```

is the same conversation where `sender_id = 5` and `receiver_id = 1`

So when I fetch the database rows, I want to have only 1 row for each conversation.

I will fetch these conversation for a specific user. the user ID (which I already know and will refer to as `userId`) can be in `sender_id` and `receiver_id`.

So my algorithm would be something like:

```
Select All rows 
from Database, 
where sender_id = userId OR receiver_id = userId, 
group by sender_id+user_id
```

the result rows have to include the other column value (not the one equal to `userId`), it can include both though and I will have to detect the other one by comparing them both to the userId I have.

To be honest I have always been uncomfortable with SQL manual. For some reason I'm failing to find what I need from there. Forgive me..

I'm not sure if I should make a temp table or use the SQL SUM function, or if I can use something like `GROUP BY sender_id+receiver_id`

More info (not sure if relevant):
I'm using php
The table has few more columns like `record_id, create_date and read_date`

Your help and replies are greatly appreciated.

Update:
The solution to my question is marked below. However, I encountered another problem that I thought of sharing, as it can maybe potentially help someone viewing this question later.

The problem I faced is, when I show the conversations, I wanna show the last message row. Now when grouping is done, the grouping stacks on the first row found. and I want the opposite. I want the rows returned to contain the last message row per conversation.

I could do that with the following query. Please note that this is only one way of doing it and I'm not yet sure of the performance of this query. I will test it later and update this if needed.

the $this->id is the id of the user I wanna display the conversations for.

```
"SELECT t1.* FROM table t1 
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT sender_id, receiver_id, max(create_date) lastCreateDate 
            FROM table 
            WHERE receiver_id = ".$this->id." OR sender_Id = ".$this->id." 
            GROUP BY GREATEST(sender_id ,receiver_id), LEAST(sender_id,receiver_id)
        ) t2
        ON ((t1.sender_id = t2.sender_id 
        OR t1.sender_id = t2.receiver_id) 
        AND t1.create_date = t2.lastCreateDate) 
        ORDER BY create_date DESC LIMIT 0,15"
```

Comment: Thanks for being specific. Next time better include examples and expected output. That makes it clearer and shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LEAST returns the lowest and GREATEST the greatest value:

```
GROUP BY LEAST(sender_id, receiver_id), GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id)
```

Comment: Hi dnoeth, thank you very much for your reply. Another issue occurred, is the results needs to be ordered by create_date DESC. When grouping, the results stack (or get grouped) on the first result found. I want this to be the opposite, I want the row returned as the last one not the first one.

Comment: What I currently have is : 
SELECT * FROM table WHERE receiver_id = ".$this->id." OR sender_Id = ".$this->id." GROUP BY GREATEST(sender_id ,receiver_id), LEAST(sender_id,receiver_id) ORDER BY create_date DESC LIMIT 0,20

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to figure it. Will add it into my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP BY max(sender_id, receiver_id), min(sender_id, receiver_id)
```

Comment: Nice one! I will try it.

Comment: You can't use an aggregate function in GROUP BY

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply m8, unfortunately I had to use GREATEST and LEAST instead of max and min to implement it on the values of the fields. Another answer already posted the right answer. I appreciate your reply greatly.

Comment: This is SQLite syntax, not MySQL syntax.